# Prioritize later observations in the scikit models in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, data-science

Given information of the following form:

```
target  f3  f2  f1  date
1   3   2   1   01/02/2000
0   6   5   4   02/02/2001
1   9   8   7   04/02/2002
1   12  11  10  06/02/2003
1   15  14  13  08/02/2004
1   18  17  16  09/02/2005
0   21  20  19  11/02/2006
1   24  23  22  13/02/2007
0   27  26  25  15/02/2008
1   30  29  28  16/02/2009
1   33  32  31  18/02/2010
1   36  35  34  20/02/2011
1   39  38  37  22/02/2012
1   42  41  40  23/02/2013
1   45  44  43  25/02/2014
```

and I know from the project domain that the world distribution is closer to the later observations but I still want to learn from the earlier observations.
There is a way to prioritize later observations in a model classification task?

Comment: Weight resampling of data toward the later times and build an ensemble model? Downsample earlier data points? Directly downweight your objective function for earlier timed data? There's no one answer for this imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is by passing `sample_weight` to the `fit` methods.
Have a look at the documentation for some of the classifiers, e.g.
[here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.fit) or [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit).
In your case you would assign higher weights to recent observations.

There is also a short illustration for the SVM classifier available in [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_weighted_samples.html).